# system verilog top configuration using `ifndefine

Tags: configuration, verilog

i have a top file that is internally configured based on the following code

```
`ifndef VAR_NAME
`define CONFIG_VARIABLE = 1
else
`define CONFIG_VARIABLE = 0
```

I would like to control the VAR_NAME from the sv test file .

How can i achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: you just cannot do it in a test. text macro definitions are compile-time property.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is make sure you compile the test file before the top file, and both files are in the same compilation unit. (meaning they can't be compiled separately.

This is a bad approach because you can't override a `` `define ``, only replace it downstream in the compilation flow. A much better approach is using parameters and have the test instantiate the top.